# How to malloc "MyDef ** t" to a specific length, instead of "MyDef * t[5]" in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, calloc

A struct like the following works fine, I can use **t** after calling **malloc(sizeof(mystruct))**:

```
struct mystruct {
 MyDef *t[5];
};
```

I want to be able to dynamically set the length of the array of **MyDef**, like the following:

```
struct mystruct {
 MyDef **t;
 int size;
};
```

What do I need to do additionally to **malloc(sizeof(mystruct))** to get this to work, so I can do **TestStruct->t[3] = something**? Just getting a segmentation fault!

Thanks!

**EDIT** with code that causes seg fault, unless I'm blind this seems to be what the answers are so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct mydef {
 int t;
 int y;
 int k;
} MyDef;

typedef struct mystruct {

 MyDef **t;
 int size;

} MyStruct;

int main(){
 MyStruct *m;

 if (m = (MyStruct *)malloc(sizeof(MyStruct)) == NULL)

  return 0;

 m->size = 11; //seg fault

 if (m->t = malloc(m->size * sizeof(*m->t)) == NULL)  

  return 0;

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

m = (MyStruct*)malloc(sizeof(MyStruct)) == NULL

What that does.  Calls malloc, compares return of malloc to NULL.  Then assigns the result of that comparison(a boolean value) to m.

The reason it does that is because '==' has a higher precedence than '='.

What you want:

```
if ( (m = (MyStruct *)malloc(sizeof(MyStruct))) == NULL)
...
if ( (m->t = malloc(m->size * sizeof(*m->t))) == NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is what I had, will edit the question with the line I have - ie this - causing a segmentation fault.

Comment: @John -- Okay, just be sure to show the actual code, not hypothetical similar code.

Comment: Using gdb, seems the seg fault occurs setting the size actually!

Answer (score 1):

```
struct mystruct *s = malloc(sizeof(*s));
s->size = 5;
s->t = malloc(sizeof(*s->t) * s->size);
```

Comment: Ok, edited the question with sample code, which seems to be doing exactly as all the answers are suggesting - get a seg fault on the line "if (m->t = malloc(m->size * sizeof(*m->t)) == NULL)"

Comment: Actually, seems the seg fault is the line setting the size - according to gdb

Comment: first line should be struct mystruct *s = malloc(sizeof(s)); otherwise it allocates ONLY the space needed for a pointer (you wrote sizeof(*s))

Comment: @Mr Shunz: No.  The type of `*s` is `struct mystruct`, not `struct mystruct *`.  IOW, `sizeof *s` == `sizeof (struct mystruct)`.

Comment: @John Richards: You're getting bitten by a precedence issue; expressions of the form `a = b == c` are parsed as `a = (b == c)`, which is not what you want here.  You need to explicitly group the assignment as `(a = b) == c`.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you do not allocate memory for array itself, only for pointer to this array.

So, first you have to allocate mystruct:

```
struct_instance = malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
```

and then you have to allocate memory for array of pointers to MyDef and initialize pointer in your struct

```
struct_instance->size = 123;
struct_instance->t = malloc(sizeof(MyDef*) * struct_instance->size);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'm sure this is what I had already tried, i'll go and check